# How to make database related nav menu like wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

Hello there today I ask very stupid question, I just make database related **nav menu** and its working properly, but my problem is when I going to set my menus or sub-menus then I do very much complex think, like, post menu name, post menu link, post sub menu location, post sub menu extension etc.
But in wordpress it seems very easy for any one,
[image]

So this my Nav Menu codes:

```
<?php
$dbcon = new MySQLi("localhost","root","","myweb");
?>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<?php
$res=$dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM main_menu");
while($row=$res->fetch_array())
{
    ?>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='<?php echo $row['m_menu_link']; ?>'><span><?php echo $row['m_menu_name']; ?></span></a>
   <?php
    $res_pro=$dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM sub_menu WHERE m_menu_id=".$row['m_menu_id']);
    ?>
      <ul>              
        <?php  
        while($pro_row=$res_pro->fetch_array())
        {
            ?><li class='has-sub'><a href="<?php echo $pro_row['s_menu_link']; ?>"><?php echo $pro_row['s_menu_name']; ?></a>

            <?php
                $res_pror=$dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM sube_menu WHERE s_menu_id=".$pro_row['s_menu_id']);
            ?>

            <ul>
                <?php  
        while($pro_rowe=$res_pror->fetch_array())
        { ?>    
               <li><a href='<?php echo $pro_rowe['s_menu_link2']; ?>'><span><?php echo $pro_rowe['s_menu_name2']; ?></span></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
            </ul>
             </li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <?php
}
?>

</ul>
</div>
```

And this is my menu setup codes, via this codes I can set my menus into database.

```
<?php
$dbcon = new MySQLi("localhost","root","","myweb");
if(isset($_POST['add_main_menu']))
{
    $menu_name = $_POST['menu_name'];
    $menu_link = $_POST['mn_link'];
    $sql=$dbcon->query("INSERT INTO main_menu(m_menu_name,m_menu_link) VALUES('$menu_name','$menu_link')");
}
if(isset($_POST['add_sub_menu']))
{
    $parent = $_POST['parent'];
    $proname = $_POST['sub_menu_name'];
    $menu_link = $_POST['sub_menu_link'];
    $sql=$dbcon->query("INSERT INTO sub_menu(m_menu_id,s_menu_name,s_menu_link) VALUES('$parent','$proname','$menu_link')");
}
if(isset($_POST['add_sub_menu2']))
{
    $parent2 = $_POST['parent2'];
    $proname2 = $_POST['sub_menu_name2'];
    $menu_link2 = $_POST['sub_menu_link2'];
    $sql=$dbcon->query("INSERT INTO sube_menu(s_menu_id,s_menu_name2,s_menu_link2) VALUES('$parent2','$proname2','$menu_link2')");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Setup menus</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="head">
</div>
<center>
<pre>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="menu name :" name="menu name" /><br />
<input type="text" placeholder="menu link :" name="mn_link" /><br />
<button type="submit" name="add_main_menu">Add main menu</button>
</form>
</pre>
<br />
<pre>
<form method="post">
<select name="parent">
<option selected="selected">select parent menu</option>
<?php
$res=$dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM main_menu");
while($row=$res->fetch_array())
{
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['m_menu_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['m_menu_name']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select><br />
<input type="text" placeholder="menu name :" name="sub_menu_name" /><br />
<input type="text" placeholder="menu link :" name="sub_menu_link" /><br />
<button type="submit" name="add_sub_menu">Add sub menu</button>
</form>
</pre>

<pre>
<form method="post">
<select name="parent2">
<option selected="selected">select parent menu</option>
<?php
$res=$dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM sub_menu");
while($row=$res->fetch_array())
{
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['s_menu_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['s_menu_name']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select><br />
<input type="text" placeholder="menu name :" name="sub_menu_name2" /><br />
<input type="text" placeholder="menu link :" name="sub_menu_link2" /><br />
<button type="submit" name="add_sub_menu2">Add sub menu2</button>
</form>
</pre>

<a href="index.php">back to main page</a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

But my point is can my codes can do like wordpress. Thank You.

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara: no I just want to make nev manu like wordpress

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara: I just want make nav menu like wordpress

Comment: @Softbazz: So you want to develop you site nav menu like wordpress? as simple I can tell it is not possible only for php, you need to build a core  **js+php**